# PC shuts down every once in a while

Tags: memory, crash, shutdown

My specs are: AMD Phenom x6 1100t processor, 2x 4 GB DDR3 RAM, and a GIGABYTE 78LMT-USB3 motherboard.

When trying to play a simple YouTube video, my machine shuts down after a few minutes. Even when playing local videos too. And it also crashed during a Fedora 22 Live CD installation.

Two of the RAM chips are nearly 4 years old. Strangely, if I disconnect one RAM, the machine works fine. But then after connecting both RAMs it doesn't boot and makes a long beep sound. Then after removing that RAM, it does the same. 
Also, the motherboard is brand new.

After a while when the motherboard is cooled down, it works fine again with 1 RAM.

Is it completely the RAM's fault? How can I check what's causing the problem? Any solution?

Comment: Which OS is this?

Answer (score 0):

Your computer crashing while playing YouTube videos may be caused by a small RAM defect. If your RAM is failing, sometimes just a small fraction of the RAM goes bad while the rest of the RAM continues to work properly. It's also possible that there may be a small amount of dirt or moisture in one of the RAM slots. Try putting the malfunctioning RAM stick in a different slot. Also try cleaning the contacts of the malfunctioning RAM with a lint-free piece of cloth.